# Change focus to next textfield in flutter

Tags: flutter, focus, flutter-layout, flutter-text

I have a code for making Text Fields as shown below

```
 ...Column(
   children: <Widget>[
                      textField(text: 'User Name'),
                      SizedBox(height: 20),
                      textField(text: 'Password'), ])...
```

textField is a class that I made that has the following code to make a textfield. I did this to avoid code duplication,since I use textfields a lot in my applicatin.

```
...TextField(
    textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
    obscureText: text == 'Password' ? true : false,
    textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
    cursorColor: primaryColor,
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      labelText: text,
      labelStyle: TextStyle(color: primaryColor, fontFamily: 'Bellotta'),
      filled: true,
      fillColor: Colors.white,
      border: OutlineInputBorder(...
```

Since I use this function to create the text field I cant use focusNode to change focus.
How can I solve this issue??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can specify two more parameter one for `focusNode` of current textfield & another one for focus u want to change e.g.

```
textField(
    text: 'User Name', 
    focusNode: // your focus node, 
    nextFocusNode: // your next field focus node
),
```

now u can use :

```
FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(nextFocus);
```

tip: if u want to decrease code duplication then instead of creating textfield method u should store ur `InputDecoration` in var/ method.

Comment: Duh that was so obvious. Cant believe I overlooked that. Thanks